# ERROR: Procedure expects a parameter, but the one it wants is an output parameter?

Tags: sql-server

I've created a procedure that has 2 input params and 1 output. I return the output at the end of the batch, now I want to exec the procedure but it won't because it says it expects a parameter of `@TotPayroll`
however I expect an output with nothing to input.

```
USE PR
GO

CREATE PROC spPayroll
            @TotPayroll money OUTPUT,
            @StartDate smalldatetime = NULL,
            @EndDate smalldatetime = NULL
AS 
IF @StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @StartDate = MIN(PerFrom) FROM vwPayCalc;
        SELECT @EndDate = MAX(PerFrom) FROM vwPayCalc;
    END
SELECT @TotPayroll = SUM(GrossPay) 
FROM vwPayCalc
WHERE PerFrom >= @StartDate AND PerFrom <= @EndDate

RETURN @TotPayroll;
GO

EXEC spPayroll
```

Comment: Default it i.e. `= null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an output parameter. You still have to supply a variable for the value to be written into<sup>1</sup>:

```
declare @payroll money

exec spPayroll @payroll OUTPUT

--do something with @payroll
```

> I return the output at the end of the batch

There's no need to do that. And in many cases trying to do so would cause an error. Stored procedures have a return value that must always be an `int`. That's what the value supplied to `return` sets. If you're lucky, your supplied value can be converted to `int`. If you're unlucky, you get a conversion error.

The return value would usually be used if you're using an "error code" convention for indicating errors back to your caller.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, you have to mark it as `OUTPUT` when calling too. Omit the `OUTPUT` here and the code will run but your variable's value will not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Return Data from a Stored Procedure

There are three ways of returning data from a procedure to a calling program: result sets, output parameters, and return codes.

I think the first way could meet your case, you can see the sample code as below

```
create proc spPayroll
@s date = null,
@e date = null
as
declare @r decimal(18,2)
set @r = 18333.11
select @r

exec spPayroll
--18333.11
```

for more detail information you could find it on the official website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#examples-of-cursor-output-parameters

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a procedure that has 2 input params and 1 output.

The procedure has 3 input parameters, one of them is also output:

```
create procedure testABC 
    @p1 int = 10,
    @p2 int = 0 output,
    @p3 int = 5
as
begin

    select @p1+@p2+@p3 as input_total;
    select @p2 = 1234;  -- output 1234
end 
go
exec dbo.testABC;
exec dbo.testABC @p2 = 1000; --@p2 is also output;
go
declare @myp2 int = 500;
exec dbo.testABC @p2 = @myp2 output;
select @myp2 as myp2outputfromproc;
go
drop procedure testABC;
```